# Is it possible to cast Arc<dyn T> into Arc<Mutex<dyn T>>?

Tags: rust, ownership

In rust, I can convert `Arc<i32>` into `Arc<Mutex<i32>>`:

```rust
let num = 5;
let arc_num = Arc::new(num);
let mtx_num = Arc::new(Mutex::new(*(arc_num.deref())));
```

But when it comes to trait, such conversion fails:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::ops::Deref;

pub trait T {}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Var {

}
impl T for Var {}

pub fn convert(var: Arc<dyn T>) -> Arc<Mutex<dyn T>> {
    return Arc::new(Mutex::new(*(var.deref())));
}
```

because `*(var.deref())` doesn't have a size known at compile-time.

So is it possible at all to convert `Arc<dyn T>` into `Arc<Mutex<dyn T>>`?

Comment: Just use something sized - a reference, a box, etc.

Comment: @Miiao those would result in different type signatures. `Arc<T>` is not the same as `Arc<&T>`

Comment: I would imagine whether or not it is sound to convert `Arc<T>` to `Arc<Mutex<T>>` has to do with the amount of reference counts the `Arc` holds. You could use [try_unwrap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.try_unwrap) to get the inner value of the `Arc` and wrap it in a new `Mutex` and `Arc`.

Comment: @MeetTitan, it’s a little rude. You’re literally trying to say “you don’t know what a reference is”. There’s no way to solve this without changing type.

Comment: @Miiao, no, I'm telling you the type signature would be different in case it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Only with help from the trait in question like this:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub trait T {
    fn mutexme(self: Arc<Self>) -> Arc<Mutex<dyn T>>;
}
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Var {}
impl T for Var {
    fn mutexme(self: Arc<Self>) -> Arc<Mutex<dyn T>> {
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(*self))
    }
}

pub fn convert(var: Arc<dyn T>) -> Arc<Mutex<dyn T>> {
    var.mutexme()
}
```

The problem is that the compiler doesn't know the size of `dyn T` so it can't reserve enough space on the stack or copy the data there.

Even if you somehow overcame that problem your `dyn T` might not be `Copy` or even `Clone` because `trait T` doesn't require that and if it did it wouldn't be [object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) since `Clone` isn't.

You also don't need to import `Deref` because you can use it with it's operator `*` like I did above.